# 'mkdir --parents' on smbclient?

Tags: linux, samba, smbclient

I have a folder tree in my linux `/home` looking like this:

```
folder/
folder/folder1/
folder/folder1/file1.csv
folder/folder1/file2.csv
folder/folder2/
folder/folder2/file3.csv
folder/folder3/file4.csv
```

I am now looping over each csv file and want to use `smbclient` to `put` the files on a windows file share. On the destination, the `folder1`, `folder2` file tree doesn't exist.

I tried

```
smbclient //server/data --command="cd path/to/destination; put /home/folder/folder1/file1.csv folder/folder1/file1.csv"
```

and get an

```
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND opening remote file \path\to\destination\folder\folder1\file1.csv
```

error because the file tree doesn't exist so far. I further tried

```
smbclient //server/data --command="cd path/to/destination; mkdir folder/folder1"
```

to create the folders before but get

```
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND making remote directory \path\to\destination\folder\folder1
```

since the smbcliend `mkdir` seems not to create also parent directories.

Is there an option in smbclient to check for existing parent directories and create them, if necessary, like the linux `mkdir --parents` option?

Comment: Can't you mount the share as CIFS?

Comment: @Tom Yan unfortunately I am not the admin for the shared folder and cannot change mount settings there.

Comment: @gehbiszumeis: "mount settings" are a client-side thing - the actual shared folder isn't going to know whether you're accessing it via `smbclient` or via `mount -t smb3` or via GVFS or something else.